# $x+y+z=3$, prove the inequality

Tags: inequality

For $x,y,z>0$ and $x+y+z=3$ prove that $\frac{x^3}{(y+2z)^2}+\frac{y^3}{(z+2x)^2}+\frac{z^3}{(x+2y)^2}\ge \frac{1}{3}$.
QM, AM, GM, HM suggested ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By C-S and C-S we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^3}{(y+2z)^2}=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}x\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^3}{(y+2z)^2}\geq\frac{1}{3}\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2}{y+2z}\right)^2\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{(x+y+z)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(y+2z)}\right)^2=\frac{1}{3}.$$

Comment: Can you please explain the second inequality?

Comment: @SamHar It's the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: For all positives $b_i$ and for all reals $a_i$ we have $\frac{a_1^2}{b_1}+\frac{a_2^2}{b_2}+...+\frac{a_n^2}{b_n}\geq\frac{(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)^2}{b_1+b_2+...+b_n}.$

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{\text{cyc}}(y+2z)=3(x+y+z)=9$$

[By Holder inequality:](https://hcmop.wordpress.com/2012/04/19/holders-inequality/)

$$\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{x^3}{(y+2z)^2}=$$

$$=\frac{\sum_{\text{cyc}}(y+2z)\sum_{\text{cyc}}(y+2z)\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{x^3}{(y+2z)^2}}{81}\ge$$

$$\ge \frac{(x+y+z)^3}{81}=\frac{1}{3}$$

Answer (score 2):

Use the inequality $\dfrac{a^3}{b^2}\geq \dfrac{2a^2}{3b} - \dfrac{a}{9}$ and then use $\dfrac{a^2}{b}\geq \dfrac{2a}{3}-\dfrac{b}{9}$, so $$\sum_{x,y,z}\dfrac{x^3}{(y+2z)^2}\geq\sum_{x,y,z}(\dfrac{x}{3} - \dfrac{2(y+2z)}{27})=\dfrac{3(x+y+z)}{27}=\dfrac{1}{3}.$$

The inequalities used are trivial AM-GM.