# $\frac{a}{(a+2b)^2}+\frac{b}{(b+2c)^2}+\frac{c}{(c+2a)^2}\ge\frac{1}{a+b+c}$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Let $a,b,c>0$. Prove that $$\frac{a}{(a+2b)^2}+\frac{b}{(b+2c)^2}+\frac{c}{(c+2a)^2}\ge\frac{1}{a+b+c}$$

**My proof:** $LHS = \frac{a^2}{a(a+2b)^2}+\frac{b^2}{b(b+2c)^2}+\frac{c^2}{c(c+2a)^2} \ge \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{a(a+2b)^2+b(b+2c)^2+c(c+2a)^2}$

But $$a(a+2b)^2+b(b+2c)^2+c(c+2a)^2$$
$$=a(a^2+4ab+4b^2)+b(b^2+4bc+4c^2)+c(c^2+4ca+4a^2)$$
$$=a^3+b^3+c^3+4(a^2b+b^2a+a^2c+c^2a+b^2c+c^2b) \ge (a+b+c)^3$$

So i stuck here for a hour and still don't understand where i get wrong. So, please help. Thank you.

**Correct solution:** $(a+b+c) \left( \frac{a}{(a+2b)^2}+\frac{b}{(b+2c)^2} +\frac{c}{(c+2a)^2}\right) \ge \left(\frac{a}{a+2b}+\frac{b}{b+2c}+\frac{c}{c+2a}\right)^2$

Now we prove $\frac{a}{a+2b}+\frac{b}{b+2c}+\frac{c}{c+2a} \ge 1$

We have $LHS=\frac{a^2}{a(a+2b)}+\frac{b^2}{b(b+2c)}+\frac{c^2}{c(c+2a)} \ge \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ca)} = 1.$
Q.E.D

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2497192/42969.

Comment: Wow, thank you, now i can do it.

Comment: @MartinR Your link has a numerator of $x^3$, but this is just $x$ (or rather $a$). Or am I missing something?

Comment: @CalvinLin: No, you are right, that was my fault. (But apparently is was of *some* help as confirmed by the author of the question.)

Comment: @tompi2394 While the linked question isn't an exact duplicate, you can easily modify the third solution in the linked question to show that Holders deals with this immediately.

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes sure, thank you.